# libusb cross compiling for raspberry pi3 on ubuntu

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3, libusb-1.0

Steps I followed to cross compile the `libusb-1.0.9` to use with already cross compiled `QT5` for `raspberry pi3`.
I have the `libusb1.0.9` folder located at   `/home/yasir/Development/crosscompile/libususb-1.0.9`

mounted image of raspberry pi3 at
    `/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/`

STEPS

step 1.

At   `/home/yasir/Development/crosscompile`
 I run this

```
./fixQualifiedLibraryPaths /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/ /home/yasir/Development/crosscompile/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

step 2.

Then I go to  `/home/yasir/Development/crosscompile/libususb-1.0.9`
 I run this

```
./configure --host=arm-linux --prefix=/usr/local/libusb-rpi  -disable-udev --with-sysroot=/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/  CROSS_COMPILE=/home/yasir/Development/crosscompile/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- CFLAGS=-I/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/include/ /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/local/include/ LIBS=-L/mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/lib
```

please note this in the mean of terminal output:
[image]

step 3

```
sudo make
```

step 4

```
sudo make install
```

[image: .so file generated]

step no 5

`make install` does copy files to `/usr/local/libusb-rpi` on the PC, but not to the image mounted. So I did this

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/local/libusb-rpi
sudo rsync -avh /usr/local/libusb-rpi/  /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs/usr/local/libusb-rpi/
```

but QT5  compiler claims that the `libusb-1.0.so`  has wrong format when I did this

```
object dump  -f libusb-1.0.so
```

which clearly shows that the `libusb -1.0.so` file is generated but not for the raspberry pi arm architecture its for the host system.

Please tell me where I am wrong. Why `libusb-1.0.so` file is not cross compiled for the arm architecture(raspberry pi3), while I have use all the correct tools for the cross compilation.

please advice so I can generate `.so` file for the rapberry pi3 through cross compilation, though I also investigated the generated `libusb.so` file at the raspberry pi3 itself ,it was found to small size and its architecture was also arm.

Comment: Seriously, don't use screenshots, just copy and paste the text!

Answer (score 1):

I used below script for configure and then a correct libusb-1.0.so  file is generated whose architecture was for arm(raspberry pi3).

```
./configure CC=/home/yasir/Development/crosscompile/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc  --host=arm-linux --enable-udev=no --enable-shared  --prefix=/usr/local/libusb-rpi
```